# Hover dialog on data table row

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to show a dialog with specific data according to the a row on a data table, like, show information about each player displayed on p:dataTable.

I'm using JSF/Primefaces.

Can anyone help, or give some light?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Instant Row Selection in Primefaces Showcase?

Here is your light: [Instant Row Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf)

Comment: Well, is not exactly what i need. Its necessary do it on row hover, i dont see an ajax behaviour to do this (on row hover).

Comment: Don't you think that even if it exists, would take too long to recover your data from the backbean? What if the user cross his pointer all over the datatable?

Comment: Yeah, but will have only one dialog, and the data will note come from server. I wonna show the state of a item, there are only 3 types, on hover of each one i pretend show the state with a small description.

Comment: If you dont want ajax behaviour for that then put one dialog box for each row.